# Different definitions of topological phases

Tags: condensed-matter, research-level, topological-field-theory, topological-order, topological-phase

When doing classification of topological phases, one need to formalize the problems mathematically. But, it seems that there are two not obviously equivalent ways to describe topological phases.

1. In Xiao-Gang Wen's papers https://arxiv.org/pdf/1004.3835.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.4772.pdf , he defined clearly local unitary (LU) transformation and topological phases which can't be connected by LU transformation. By adding some restrictions  to LU  transformation (such as symmetry), we get SPT or SET phases. It has nice argument showing that bosonic SPT is classified by group cohomology.
2. In Anton Kapustin's papers (such as https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05856.pdf and https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.01640.pdf ), he considered a topological phase as  an (invertible) topological quantum field theory (TQFT). He argued that TQFT encodes the low energy continuum limit of the corresponding Hamiltonian, but the one-one correspondence is unclear.

I can understand why topological phases are related to TQFT, but how do we show that they are the same thing? More precisely, can we prove the equivalence between connectedness of product states by LU transformation and (invertible) TQFT?

Comment: Any hint or idea of the relation between topological phase and TQFT will be very helpful.

Comment: In many exemples on topological phase using the formalism of field theory, the topological quantum field theory is in fact not quantised. That's perhaps why you do not see the connection between LU and TQFT. In any case you're asking about an active field of research.